# Generating combinations of elements of 2 lists in sets of 3 in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have 2 lists below

```
list_1 = ['A','B','C']
list_2 = ['D','E','F']
```

Trying to generate combinations to replicate the below output

```
(AD, BE, CF), (AD, BF, CE), (AE, BD, CF), (AE, BF, CD), (AF, BD, CE) (AF, BE, CD)
```

So far I have been able to create the combinations by using itertools.

```
list = [list_1, list_2]

combination = [p for p in itertools.product(*list)]
```

which gives me

```
[('A', 'D'),
 ('A', 'E'),
 ('A', 'F'),
 ('B', 'D'),
 ('B', 'E'),
 ('B', 'F'),
 ('C', 'D'),
 ('C', 'E'),
 ('C', 'F')]
```

but not sure how to proceed further from this.

Comment: This is a task, not a question. What have you tried, why did it fail?

Comment: The first list and its items order doesn't change between result tuples, only the second list is **permutated**

Answer (score 2):

Just `zip` the first list with all permutations of the second one:

```
from itertools import permutations

def combs(l1, l2):
    for p in permutations(l2, len(l2)):
        yield list(map(''.join, zip(l1, p)))
        # or simpler:
        # yield [a+b for a, b in zip(l1, p)]

>>> list(combs(list_1, list_2))
[['AD', 'BE', 'CF'], ['AD', 'BF', 'CE'], ['AE', 'BD', 'CF'], ['AE', 'BF', 'CD'], ['AF', 'BD', 'CE'], ['AF', 'BE', 'CD']]
```

Some docs:

- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)
- [generator functions (`yield` keyword)](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators)